# Encrypted text comes out wrong

Tags: android, encryption

Hi I have some code which encrypts a text and display it in a textView and send it as an SMS.

The algorithm is (letterInt * constant)%29 = new letterInt

so basically it is the leftovers of division of 29 on the letter value times the constant

The alphabet is like this

```
private List<Character> alfabet = new ArrayList<Character>();
    alfabet.add('a');
    alfabet.add('b');
    alfabet.add('c');
    alfabet.add('d');
    alfabet.add('e');
    alfabet.add('f');
    alfabet.add('g');
    alfabet.add('h');
    alfabet.add('i');
    alfabet.add('j');
    alfabet.add('k');
    alfabet.add('l');
    alfabet.add('m');
    alfabet.add('n');
    alfabet.add('o');
    alfabet.add('p');
    alfabet.add('q');
    alfabet.add('r');
    alfabet.add('s');
    alfabet.add('t');
    alfabet.add('u');
    alfabet.add('v');
    alfabet.add('w');
    alfabet.add('x');
    alfabet.add('y');
    alfabet.add('z');
    alfabet.add('æ');
    alfabet.add('ø');
    alfabet.add('å');
```

The problem is, that whenever C becomes larger than 1 the text isnt encrypted corretly.
e.g. d = 4, but if i choose C = 4 then the output becomes h (8), not p (16).

The code part is like this:

```
        char[] bogstaver = tekstString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 1; i <= bogstaver.length; i++) {
            if (bogstaver[i-1] == ' ' || bogstaver[i-1] == '.' || bogstaver[i-1] == '?' || bogstaver[i-1] == '!' ||
                    bogstaver[i-1] == ',' || bogstaver[i-1] == ';' || bogstaver[i-1] == '+' || bogstaver[i-1] == '(' || 
                    bogstaver[i-1] == ')' || bogstaver[i-1] == '{' || bogstaver[i-1] == '}' || bogstaver[i-1] == ':'){
                    continue;   
            }

            if( CType == 1){
                C = Integer.valueOf(faktorA);
                CType = 2;
            }
            else if (CType == 2){
                C = Integer.valueOf(faktorB);
                CType = 3;
            }
            else if (CType == 3){
                C = Integer.valueOf(faktorE);
                CType = 1;
            }

            bogstaver[i-1] = alfabet.get((alfabet.indexOf(bogstaver[i-1]) * C)%29);
        }
        String endeligeTekst = new String(bogstaver);
        if (k == 1){
            krypteredeTekst.setText(endeligeTekst);
        }
        else{
            sendString(endeligeTekst, Nr);
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain the encryption algorithm you use, please?

Comment: Could you add the definition of 'alfabet'?

Comment: Now i have added both algorithm and alphabet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you're not getting the result you're expecting;

`e` is the 4th value in your List (it's 0 indexed, `a=0`, `b=1` etc.

With `C=3`, the result is 4*3=12, and the 13'th character (at index 12) is `m` which is the output (I can't get `n` as your question states).